# Coding inside script tags that load external js files

Tags: javascript, html

I did a random experiment and tried to do write inside script tag that loads external js files and call one of the methods and it didn't work. This is my js file

```
//external.js
var myObject = {
    myMethod: function(){
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = "Hello, Internet!"
    }
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js">
    myObject.myMethod();
</script>
```

So I have two questions. One is obviously why didn't the method get called? Second is why were there no errors in my console? eg: myObject.myMethod is not a function

Comment: Try `var myObject = {
    myMethod: function(){
        debugger;
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = "Hello, Internet!"
    }
}` Keep your developer tools open..

Comment: do you have a sample of how you loaded the external script ?

Comment: the code  between tags will be ignored if you have a src with value

Comment: to fix it add the code in other script tag <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
    myObject.myMethod();
</script>  for explanation see my below answer

Answer (score 1):

Code within `<script src="–">` elements that reference files via the src attribute *does not get executed*. This is explained in [Restrictions for contents of script elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements), but no browser "enforces" the "must be comment content" thing.

[Identifying the current `<script>` element](http://www.2ality.com/2014/05/current-script.html) explains how this behavior can be used to parameterize script execution.

Answer (score 0):

Put the function call in your external JavaScript file like so:

```
var myObject = {
    myMethod: function(){
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = "Hello, Internet!"
    }
}

myObject.myMethod();
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1

> The script may be defined within the contents of the SCRIPT element or
>   in an external file. If the src attribute is not set, user agents must
>   interpret the contents of the element as the script. If the src has a
>   URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve
>   the script via the URI. Note that the charset attribute refers to the
>   character encoding of the script designated by the src attribute; it
>   does not concern the content of the SCRIPT element.

Comment: How does this answer this question ?